# Как поменять изображение checkBox

Tags: android

Как поменять картинку у checkBox? У меня есть список каталогов. Есть возможность выбора этих каталогов, если каталог выбран то в чекбоксе напротив него ставиться галочка.  Если каталог не выбран, то  чекбокс напротив него пустой. Мне нужно как-то отметить третье состояние, когда внутри каталога есть выбранные подкаталоги, но сам этот каталог не выбран.

Comment: очень просто  - дождаться  полка телепаты выйдут из отпуска и расшифруют вопрос, есть более сложный и долгий путь попытаться более подробно написать что нужно))

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что вы хотите получить что-то типа такого?

![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/5niAmBy.png

Comment: да! именно это

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Придется делать вместо Checkbox обычный ImageView.
Затем менять картинку, в зависимости от 3х вариантов: да, нет, частично.
изменять методом:

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checked);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unchecked);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.both);
```

Answer (score 2):

Тогда сделай кастомный чекбокс и определяй какой нужен, в зависимости от этого задаешь background - если каталог выбран, или в нем нет выбранных подкаталогов - обычный, есть выбранные подкаталоги кастомный.

---

Да кастомный только для третьего состояния, когда есть подкаталоги, в остальных случаях хватит обычного   чекбокса.
Скрин вставляется  с      помощью кнопки
[image]

Comment: "есть выбранные подкаталоги кастомный" ты имеешь ввиду, кастомный чекбокс для третьего состояния использовать, а для двух других исползовтаь обычный чексбок. Или просто менять background для третьего состояния, а для двух других не менять background? И еще, как я могу свой скрин сюда кинуть?

Answer (score 0):

```
<CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/cbHelper"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:button="@drawable/check_box"
                    android:checked="true"/>
```

В папке dravable сделай файл check_box.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
android:state_checked="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/check_box1" />  // картинка с галочкой
<item
android:state_checked="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/check_box2" />  // картинка с крестиком
</selector>
```

Картинки check_box1 и check_box2 в формате png положи тут же, в папку dravable.

Comment: нужно для трех состояний чекбокс